# Dynamic image for Google Maps Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map on which I display public transit stops. I would like to color code those stops according to various parameters. I would also like to use my own icon. I have figured out how to take a png image and change its color in javascript, but I'm not sure how to get the Google Map to use it as the Marker image.

I've seen the [Styled Marker library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/) but as far as I can tell, you can't use your own image with it--and from an (admittedly cursory) look at its source, I don't think I can change it to use my image as it seems to use URL parameters with a set of default markers to achieve the color change.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you display the image in a browser?  If there is a URL, then you can just use a normal marker.  You can also load it as a [base64 encoded data URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095102/how-do-i-load-binary-image-data-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: I use this technique to get the image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303757/how-to-change-color-of-an-image-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: false,
    raiseOnDrag: false,
    icon: {
      size: new google.maps.Size(32, 42),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 42),
      url: // path to png
    },
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map
  });
```

[Here's the full documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a path to the png--I want to change the colors of the icon on the fly, hence dynamically.