# How to change the color of an image in PHP, keeping shadows

Tags: php, colors

I need to change the colors of a template using PHP and keeping the shades of shadows.

The template has three colors: 
Color 1: Red 
Color 2: White 
Color 3: black 
 
A user will choose three colors from the palette to be replaced by the color 1, 2 and 3, keeping the shades of shadows. Any idea how to do it?

Example image http://imageshack.com/a/img28/9914/042s.png

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery could solve your problem. Checkout the following link. It could give you a start at least.

[How to change color of an image using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303757/how-to-change-color-of-an-image-using-jquery)